# Installing Boost to custom directory

Tags: c++, boost

I have tried following [the tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) Boost gives on their documentation for installing boost and have looked at a few other questions here to try to determine why I can't install Boost at a custom location. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but the `--prefix` option is supposed to specify where the Boost headers and libs will go, then `bootstrapper.sh` creates a `.jam` file that is used when `b2` or `bjam` is run.

When I issue the following command

```
 ./bootstrap.sh --prefix="$HOME/dev/emulator/src/boost" --includedir=headers --libdir=dist --with-libraries=date_time
```

I see that the correct lines are added to the generated `project-config.jam` file

```
option.set prefix : /home/liam/dev/emulator/src/boost ;
option.set exec-prefix : /home/liam/dev/emulator/src/boost ;
option.set libdir : dist ;
option.set includedir : headers ;
```

However, when I run `./b2` as instructed by the documentation, it installs the Boost libraries to the source folder; i.e.

```
The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /home/liam/Downloads/brave/boost_1_66_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /home/liam/Downloads/brave/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib
```

And running `./b2 install` gives me no file output to the intended directory either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use your directory in both steps:

```
DST_DIR=${HOME}/dev/emulator/src/boost

./bootstrap.sh --prefix=${DST_DIR} --includedir=headers --libdir=dist --with-libraries=date_time
./b2 --prefix=${DST_DIR} install
```

Comment: This fixed my problem. Just wish there was a way to build date_time and not copy all of Boost.

Comment: Is there a way that I can just install the built libraries without installing the header files?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=path/to/installation/prefix
./b2 install
```

So that means first bootstrap b2 and then use it to build and install boost.

Comment: I've tried `./b2 install --prefix="$HOME/dev/emulator/src/boost" --includedir=headers --libdir=dist --with-date_time`, but I get no output at $HOME/dev/emulator/src/boost.

Comment: For me this worked whereas the `./b2 --prefix ..` did not